# What is the effect of normal reaction at round corners? Should we consider the case of collision at corners? or it is a kind of circular motion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, energy-conservation

$A B C D$ is a rhombus shaped tube with rounded corners (Fig). It lies in a vertical plane. A ball is made to roll from $A$ to $B$ to $C$. Next the same ball is made to roll from $A$ to $D$ to $C .$ In which of the two cases will it take less time?

[image: figure]

Comment: You are overthinking the question- the answer is quite simple. Also, you should at least show that you have made an effort to work it out for yourself.

Comment: @MarcoOcram I thought that if collision is inelastic at B&D point they will loose maximum speed at those points .Along BC side it has more acceleration as compared to dc side so to cover the distance BC it would take less time so the answer should be ABC path. Please guide me  .thanks

Comment: There is no information in the question about the elasticity of the ball or of the material from which the tube is constructed, so it is impossible to work out the effects relating to elasticity. Given that, you have to assume that the point of the question has nothing to do with elasticity per se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that the path ADC will be the quicker, because the ball undergoes the higher rate of acceleration first, and therefore completes the DC section at a relatively high speed compared with the speed at which it would have completed the corresponding AB section had it taken the other route.

There is no information in the question about the elasticity of the ball or the tube, so you should conclude that the question does not expect you to consider such complications.